# XSS payload not executing because of different double quote

Tags: javascript, xss, penetration-testing

I am doing penetration testing of a website where I am trying to execute a stored xss payload through one of the input parameter. Application had special case validation on client side, so I intercepted the request in Burp and added %22(which is a double quote **"**) to the input parameter.

Now the problem is, when the page is reflecting this input parameter with the double quote that I injected, it is not looking like a regular double quote ("). Instead it looks like it is in italics. This is how it looks in browser now (”) but I am expecting it to look like (")

What could be going on here? Why does my double quote look like this ” in browser when it is reflecting back?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What could be going on here?

Well, without seeing the source code, all we can do is speculate. It could perhaps be the developer's way of encoding output server-side. Just like how we often convert `"` to `&quot;` to prevent XSS, they may be doing something where they convert it to `&#8221;` if there is a space to the right, and `&#8220;` if there is a space to the left to create "fancy" quotes.

I would try payloads like this:

- `test%22%20test` - `test" test` - did it get changed to close quote?
- `test%20%22test` - `test "test` - did it get changed to open quote?
- `%22te%22st%22` - `"te"st"` - what happened to the middle quote? Any difference in behavior?
- `test%22%0atest` - `test"\ntest"` - did using a newline change anything?
- `test%5c%22test` - `test\"test"` - did a backslash change anything?
- `%22%22%22%22%22%22%22%22` - `""""""""` - which quotes got encoded? what happens if I use more/less quotes. odd/even. etc.

It kind of depends on the answers to those questions, but if all quotes are encoded (regardless of if they become fancy unicode quotes or if they become `&quote;`) then it may simply not be possible to get XSS if you are "trapped" in a string.

In the future, it may be helpful you include the HTML output (anonymized as necessary).

Comment: Hello Gray,  Thanks for your inputs.  I tried all of your suggestions and it looks like I am not able to break out of string.  In all cases, the double quote became like fancy quote.   For example,                             
odd: TRY”””””””””””WITH
even: TRY””””””””””WITH . I apologize for not formatting my comment properly. I am still trying to get used to the formatting. I would like to thank a lot for your inputs. Though the XSS was not successful, i really did learn from inputs.     Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm glad it helped. It's always disappointing when it seems like there **has** to be a vulnerability, but you just can't get it to work, haha. I learned a lot about XSS from games like this: https://alf.nu/alert1 - pretty good exercises for getting you to think out of the box (and learn a few new tricks). Good luck!

Comment: Yes unfortunately I spent too many hours on this. Thanks a lot for the exercise link.